# The div and images are not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have places a static banner from snapdeal but the banner runs out of its container box. The static banner is a JavaScript with fixed height and width mentioned in it.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">TITLE</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div data-SDID="someidhere"  data-identifier="SnapdealAffiliateAds" data-height="auto" data-width="auto" >
            </div><script async id="snap_zxcvbnhg" src="https://affiliate-ads.snapdeal.com/affiliate/js/snapdealAffiliate.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used following jQuery in head section (also tried it after body) to add responsive classes to the image I get from snapdeal:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("img").addClass("img");
        $("img").addClass("img-responsive");
    });
</script>
```

but, no luck. What can I try next?

Comment: Do you expect the banner to just smush together horizontally?

Comment: what do you mean, runs out of the container box ? I dont see the size overflowing its container. I just see the image at the center of its container

Comment: *a javascript with fixed height and width* .... so how do you expect it will be responsive ?? ... Maybe the only aproach is to force % dimensions with JS or CSS

Comment: Is it being pulled in through an iframe? What does the final rendered result look like?

Comment: actually, the view in mobile is fine, but on laptop, the tiles get out of the container. I tried auto in place of fix width, still it didnt work because the script overrides the dimensions at runtime. please see the view-source of showdeal.in for rendered result.